# Why the result of Index::index is dereferenced?

Tags: rust

I have some code like this

```rust
struct MyStruct {
    id: u32
}

fn main() {
    let vec: Vec<MyStruct> = vec![MyStruct {
        id: 1
    }];
    let my_struct = vec[0];
}
```

I thought `my_struct` must be of reference type, but the compiler proved I was wrong:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of index of `Vec<MyStruct>`
  --> src/main.rs:10:21
   |
10 |     let my_struct = vec[0];
   |                     ^^^^^^ move occurs because value has type `MyStruct`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |
help: consider borrowing here
   |
10 |     let my_struct = &vec[0];
```

So I read the doc of trait `Index` and noticed the sentence below:

> container[index] is actually syntactic sugar for *container.index(index)

It's counterintuitive. Why rust dereferences it? Does it mean that it's more friendly to types those impl `Copy`?

Comment: One reason is to match the semantics of other languages like C++. Every language I know of returns values, not pointers, when indexing an array. Another reason is to make assignments work (though that's a bit complicated).

Comment: I wouldn't describe it as rust auto-derefenfrencing, I see it as rust not automatically borrowing it. To me it is the most intuitive way but that may be because I have done a fair amount of C/C++ and been using rust for a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are plenty of other questions asking about this ([1](/q/71981790/2189130) [2](/q/69342374/2189130) [3](/q/65212978/2189130)) but none really address the *why* part.

Rust has made many design decisions work to make ownership clear. For example, you cannot pass a value, `v`, directly to a function `f` that expects a reference. It must be `f(&v)`. There are places where this isn't always the case (macros like `println!` and auto-ref for method calls being prime exceptions), but many parts of the language follow this principle.

The behavior of the index operator is pretty much the same as the normal field access operator `.`. If you have `my_struct: &MyStruct` then `my_struct.id` will yield a `u32` and not a `&u32`. The default behavior is to *move* fields. You have to introduce a `&` (i.e. `&my_struct.id`) to get a reference to the field. So the same is with the index operator. If you want to make it clear that you want only a *reference* to the element, then you need to introduce a `&`.